# Updating php variable

Tags: php

I'm trying to figure out why my PHP var does not update.
I tried multiple solutions, not sure if i am doing something wrong, or this does just not work.

Any tips are appreciated.

```
<form method="post">
  <button type="submit" name="test"> 10  </button>
</form>

<?php
    if(!isset($_SESSION['money']))
    {
       $_SESSION['money'] = 100;
    }

    if(isset($_POST['test']))
    {
        $money = $_SESSION['money'];
        $money++;
        $_SESSION['money']= $money;
        echo $money;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't seems to have started the session. Make sure you've put the line `session_start();` at the top of your php files

Comment: Wow, beginners mistake ! Totally missed that, thanks alot!

Comment: No problem ;-) Could you please mark answer as solved ?

Comment: Will do, in 6 minutes. SO has a timer on the solved answer.

Answer (score 1):

missing session and action

```
<?php session_start();  ?>
<form method="post" action="">
  <button type="submit" name="test"> 10  </button>
</form>

<?php
    if(!isset($_SESSION['money']))
    {
       $_SESSION['money'] = 100;
    }

    if(isset($_POST['test']))
    {
        $money = $_SESSION['money'];
        $money++;
        $_SESSION['money']= $money;
        echo $money;
    }
?>
```